# Struggling with using drop-down input menus to calculate & print results

Tags: html, css

[HTML, JS, CSS]
.
I'm trying to make code for a dining calculator that takes an inputted value, inputted tip amount (from a drop-down menu), and an inputted amount of customers (also from a drop-down menu), then calculates **([startPrice * tipAmount] + [startPrice/peopleEating])** and prints the results.

The problem is that I don't know how to calculate and print results using the inputted values of those drop-down menus. Can anyone give me a simple explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: Post the code you have so far as a code snippet and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use the `.value` of the dropdown. I have attached a runnable code snippet below:

```js
function processForm() {
      var startPrice = document.getElementById("startPrice").value;
      var tipAmount = document.getElementById("tipAmount").value;
      var peopleEating = document.getElementById("peopleEating").value;
      console.log("Start price is " + startPrice);
      console.log("Tip Amount is " + tipAmount);
      console.log("People Eating is " + peopleEating);
      console.log((startPrice * Number(tipAmount)) + (startPrice/Number(peopleEating)) + " Is the calculated number");
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <label for="startPrice">Start Price</label>
  <input type="number" name="startPrice" id="startPrice"><br><br>
  <label for="tipAmount">Tip Amount</label>
  <select id="tipAmount" name="tipAmount">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
  </select><br><br>
  <label for="peopleEating">People Eating</label>
  <select id="peopleEating" name="peopleEating">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="processForm()">Calculate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS**: I have used the `Number()` function in the dropdown values, because by default they are stored as strings, and converting them into numbers is important.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code wasn't perfect but it helped me understand the theory enough to make a working calculator.